# pdf into latex: suggestions

Tags: graphics, pdf

I would like to ask you how to insert a PDF in a LaTeX page.
I did, but [it does not look very nice](http://www.dmi.unict.it/~difazio/Figura.pdf):

[image]

Could you suggest me some improvement?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? For this kind of purposes, the [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package is the right tool, but if your aim is to insert the figure, well, it is simple and you can draw it.

Comment: Probably the figure has a lot of white space around. You should check the original pdf, with Inkscape for example, looking for the page size. Anyway, I would suggest you to redraw the figure (using `tikz`, for example).

Comment: I could `includegraphics{Figura}` and get good resolution pdf in evince. May it is because of pdf reader try a [different one](http://wiki.fsfe.org/PDFreaders/todo2012/Overview-Page)

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to build tables showing the variations of functions, you could have a look to the `variations` package, which produces the following ouput :

[image: variations table]

with the code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{variations}
\begin{document}
\def\isq{\frac{1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\centering
    \begin{variations}
     x      & \mI &    &-\isq &    & \isq  &    & \pI  \\
     \filet
     f'     & \ga +    & 0    &  -  &  0   & \dr+      \\
     \filet
     \m{f}  & ~  & \c  & \h{~} & \d & ~    &  \c       \\
     \end{variations}
\end{minipage}  
\end{document}
```